# Cannot boot into Android after freezing Blink Feed Launcher in HTC One M7

Tags: boot, htc-one, disable-app

Using Titanium Backup Pro I froze Blink Feed Launcher.
Now all I see on the screen is just logo and bootloader page by using Power and Volume buttton. I have an HTC One M7 running Lollipop 5.0.2.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Blink Feed Launcher is the launcher app for your HTC One M7 and with this frozen you'll be unable to use your phone.

Factory reset will be the simplest and easiest option available, and since you're using [Titanium Backup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), I must assume that you have a backup of all your user apps, and as such you can restore them after the factory reset. If not then you'll have to re-download them all from Google Play Store.